# Ammo converter missing after moving C.A.M.P

Tags: fallout-76

I've bought an Ammo Converter from the Atom store. It wasn't the best investment, but hey, I've managed to place it inside a shack that is a core of my camp. Unfortunately, I forgot to modify the blueprint for the shack...

When I've moved the camp, the converter is no longer inside the shack - this was to be expected, as the blueprint hasn't been updated. However, the ammo converter is not on the list of the stored items (where usually end up loose contraptions that haven't been merged together in a blueprint) and when I am trying to build a new one, I've got an info that the maximum number of such types of objects (1/1) has already been built.

How can I get my converter back?

Comment: Try resetting your CAMP

Comment: Given the fact that the game is extremely buggy, I'd assume that the convert either spawned below/above or just disappeared entirely. Maybe you can find it somewhere, but if not, the only thing you can do is tear your camp down and rebuild it. This bug used to be very common back then with plants like corn.

Answer (score 1):

OK, fixed:

After moving the C.A.M.P again, I've noticed that I had in storage...two shacks! One was the same from the not-updated blueprint, the other one was looking exactly like the shack that I've lost before the first move.

However, I couldn't put the "updated" shack in place - whenever I tried, the game was saying that "the structure needs support", even while the structure was placed in a valid space. So, after a bit of experimenting I've found a solution:

1. I've placed the blueprint shack on a ground
2. I've pulled out from the building menu the "new" shack
3. I've selected the scrap/store option. This gave me also an option to split the shack into basic components
4. I've put the missing ammo converter into the shack from the blueprint and updated the blueprint.

What is interesting, is the fact that after step #3 ALL the content of the shack became available for placing, which in effect doubled the content of the shack - I have now 2 armour workbenches, 2 tinker workbenches etc. Kind of an exploitable solution, because I can scrap the double-ups and have free resources while keeping the working devices.

Comment: This kind of problems seems endemic to fallout 76. I know I’ve had it happen to me with decorative CAMP wall art